# In whick method dialog should be dismissed

Tags: android

Since the dialogs must be dismissed before leaving the activity, I override the `onSaveInstanceState()` method in my activity to save the data of dialog before. I think after taking the data from activity i should call the `dismiss()` method on dialog at last of `onSaveInstanceState()`. Am I right?

Comment: Try to do this onPause or before calling the finish method of the activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to call `dismiss()` on the Dialog you created in view before exiting the Activity, e.g. in `onPause()`. All windows&dialogs should be closed before leaving an Activity.If you dont dismiss the dialog it will give you that exception.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, dialog will be dismissed after calling dialog.dismiss() method and assign dialog=null also, so you would be saved against Window Leaked error.

Comment: means, calling dismiss() at last of onSaveInstanceState() is fine?

Comment: Why are you not dismmising the dialog in onPause or onStop, do it in this methods.

Comment: Since, i am new to android, so i am trying to save the data of dialog in Bundle in onSaveInstanceState() method. So i am dismissing dialog in onSaveInstanceState() after the data from it.

Comment: its not the issue, you can save data with any other type and you can dismiss the dialog in onSavedInstanceState also.